# Find blank cells in column and put in VLookup formula, but only if there is a value in another cell in a different column

Tags: excel, vba, formula, vlookup

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- On Sheet1, look for blank cells in columns O, Q, Z, AC, and put in a Vlookup formula (referencing sheet2).
- But only put in the Vlookup formula if there is a value (name) in column B (in the same row and on the same Sheet1).

The first blank cell in column O, Q, Z, AC is random because I get different data daily.
Here's what I've pieced together for column O, but it doesn't work.

```
Sub BegBalance()
'
' BegBalance Macro
' Adding formula to pull in beginning balance

    Dim lFirstBlank As Long, lLastRow As Long
    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim srchres As Variant

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    lFirstBlank = _
    Range("O2:O" & lLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells(1, 1).Row

    Set rRange = Range("O" & lFirstBlank & ":O" & _
    lLastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)

    On Error Resume Next
    srchres = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ws1.Range("B2"), ws2.Range("B:H"), 3, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If (IsEmpty(srchres)) Then
        ws1.Range("O2").Formula = CVErr(Error)
    Else
        ws2.Range("O2").Value = srchres
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: what specifically do you mean, "it doesn't work"?

Comment: You want to find the first blank row in each of those columns AND IF column B holds a valid name (string) you then want to perform a VLookup to another sheet/range and insert the returned match to this blank cell?  Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work meaning the Vlookup formula is not inserted in the blank cells in the column O. For example, I want to find all blank cells in column O and put in the Vlookup formula only if there's a name in column B on the same row.  If cell O3 is blank and cell B3 has a name then insert the Vlookup formula.  if cell O4 is blank but there's nothing in B3, then don't put in the Vlookup formula. If O5 is not blank and then skip and look for the next blank cell in column O. I want to do this for columns O, Q, Z, AC and put in 4 different Vlookup formulas. Hope that's more clear :)